# RegEx validation in XML schema

Tags: xml, regex, web-services

```
<xs:simpleType name="Personalname">
<xs:restriction base="xs:string">
<xs:pattern value=".{0,0}|\w+([-]\w+)*( (\w)+)+"/>
</xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

I am trying to restrict my XML Input Values to the above pattern.It can accept hyphen between two names.

This should except names like "Ankit Bansal" or "Ankit-Bansal Agarwal" 0r "Ankit Bansal Bansal" according to the logic in the pattern

But whenever I run with the following pattern it gives me an error like

> [CDATA[The 'Personalname' element has an invalid value according to its data type. An error occurred at , (1, 329).]

Comment: `.{0,0}` -> It should be safe to throw this away (but leave the `|` alone) (not an answer to your problem)

Comment: Okay...That is anyways not the solution to the problem.The main part of the problem is with after the | symbol

Answer (score 0):

```
^((?:(?:\b[A-Za-z0-9]+[ -])+)\w+)$
```

You can try this.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/xT7yD8/11

Comment: Thanks..Its validating successfully in the compiler.But in my code there is same error given.The original string which I am trying to change is "<xs:pattern value="(\w)+( (\w)+)+"/>"

Comment: @AnkitBansal try removing `^` and `$` and try again

Comment: The expression you gave excepts "Ankit Bansal" but does not except "Ankit-Bansal bansal" etc...I think there is some other validation which is causing the issue...But according to my knowledge this error is only received when the xml validation fails.

Comment: @AnkitBansal it accepts `Ankit-Bansal bansal`as you can see in demo.There has to some other issue